# What is the ideal way to declare a const string as a struct member in C?

Tags: c, string

I have an object with member title, which I would like to treat as a mutable string. In this example, it would only be valid if I set the array to a fixed size, but I'm reading xml and can't decide on a predictable length. I'd go with a character pointer, but than I have to manage it with free because otherwise it is stored throughout the lifetime of the execution. I'm pretty stumped deciding the best way to handle this.

```
typedef struct
{
    const char title[];
    const size_t title_length;
    ...
}item;
```

Comment: Don't declare `struct` members `const`.  It causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: "*than I have to manage it with free*". What is the issue with that? If you are going to write C programs then managing dynamic memory is something you almost certainly need to do at some point. And how does making the string `const` help anyway?

Comment: @kaylum I never claimed const was there to help, just imply the value isn't to be changed.

Comment: "just imply the value isn't to be changed" --> consider `const char *title;` to prevent changing of the _string_.  `title` is not `const`.  The string it points to is not changed via accessing this member.

Comment: `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free` are essential parts of the C language, and they are there for uses such as this. Use them and get comfortable with it. Seeking to avoid them is the wrong course.

Comment: A string you read from XML is not `const`. Do not try to define it as `const`.

Answer (score 1):

"string" is not a solidly defined thing in C.  It is (generally) a sequence of `char` characters in a `char` array somewhere in memory, terminated by a NUL character.  So concretely, it might be an array or it might be a pointer into an array.  The size of the array might match the size of the string, or it might be larger, and if you just have a pointer there is no way to tell.  If you want to read a string from somewhere (an XML file?) you'll generally want it to NOT be const.  If you don't know how big it will be until you read it, you'll generally need to do some resizing of the array, so will probably need dynamic memory (malloc/realloc).

So what you'll generally have is something like:

```
struct item {
    char *title;    /* points at an array that will hold the title */
    size_t title_capacity;   /* the size allocated for the `title` array */
    ...
};
```

Comment: As long as I free *title, will it no longer be stored anywhere? Also with char pointers, as long as you know the length, is a null terminator really necessary? Forgive me, I'm very new to C.

Comment: The NUL terminator is necessary if you want to use any functions that take a string, such as strlen, printf, etc.

Comment: @Tim: If you have the size of the string, you do not need a null terminator, because but you will have to br careful not to use it in a way that requires a null terminator.